# Autocomplete when editing file links

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-link, doom

When I insert a link into an org-file using `C-c C-l` (Doom Emacs, if that matters) and select `file:`, it show me the files in the current directory to autocomplete from. However, when editing such a link with `C-c C-l`, there's no auto-completion anymore. Can I change this somehow?

[This mailing thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-01/msg00177.html) seems to talk of the same issue, but using `C-u C-c C-l` as suggested there doesn't work - `C-u` immediately jumps up (I guess due to evil).